# When the Gain Margin is negative, for what range of frequencies is will the output resonate out of control?

Tags: frequency, control-system, gain, bode-plot

If your system/transfer function has greater than zero gain for the frequency associated with -180 degrees phase, the system is said to be **unstable**. What does this mean for other input frequencies?

Does this mean that *any* input frequency would result in an unstably growing output? Or just a certain range of frequencies?

Bode plot for use as reference:

[image: Bode Plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a real system there will always be some component of noise or input signal at the frequency, so the output will grow until it hits some limit (saturates or whatever).

Comment: Cheers! So have I got this right?

We'd expect some non-zero noise at the frequencies that result in unstable feedback and then the system sees them growing from negligible to saturated?

Comment: precisely. Every signal carries a bit of every frequency because every physic signal is time limited, so its fourier transform can't be frequency limited.

Comment: In reality, it is not the noise that brings the amplifier into saturation but the supply voltage switch-on transients (because these effects dominate over the noise). In short: If a circuit is unstable it will oscillate or go into saturation - indepent on any input signal.

Comment: @LvW True, but my point was even that if you allowed the system to reach equilibrium then close the loop, in a real system it will oscillate (it may not in simulation). It's like it was balanced on a knife edge, anything will set it off.